Excel xlam addin - handling addin paths when switching locations
I have an excel add-in (xlam) that i am working on along with a corresponding xlsx file that will use the addin. i need to distribute both of these to users.  To avoid having to deal with user specific add-in paths, Before distributing, i copy the xlam to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\xlstart\, open the xlsx and add the addin-in from that path, make sure all the custom formulas work and save it.  then distribute.
The distribution process involves copying the latest xlam file to the users C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\xlstart\ as well.  But when they use the xlx, they should be fine and no errors about broken links or formula errors happen.  it works (though horribly kludgy i know).
the xlx has come cells that use custom functions and references these like this
=custom_func("test", "ctx1","01/01/1999","02/28/1999",,"D")

The problem is when i want to work on the add-in code, which i do in my local dev folders.
here i open the spreadsheet and specifically add the addin in the dev location, save and re-open.  when i do this however, the cells that contain custom formulas look like this:
='C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\xlstart\myaddin.xlam'!custom_func("test", "ctx1","01/01/1999","02/28/1999",,"D")

Note that it is now referencing the old path.  I can fix this manually or by change the linked file source, but i wonder:

if there is a better way to do this
can i through vba programmatically remove the xlam file so the formula does not reference any specific external worksheet, but would instead use the current addin loaded?

Through vba i have tried the following to try and identify these 'broken' formulas with the now bad external link, but it does not highlight anything:
Sub FindBrokenFormula()
    Dim r As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng1 = ws.UsedRange.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            For Each r In rng1
                If r.Errors.item(xlInconsistentFormula).value = True Then
                    r.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End If
            Next r
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

I figured if i could identify them efficiently, i can on startup of the add-in, simply strip out the external workbook reference - which hopefully means it will default to expecting and using the formula from the current addd-in
any suggestions?
